# PostgreSQL: Why can't I add two MAX to this view

Tags: sql, postgresql, dataview

I am trying to create a simple view using the following query:

```
SELECT 
MAX(row)
,"Email"
,MAX("DateUpdated")

FROM

"Staging"."DuplicateSubscribers"

GROUP BY "Email"
```

It is throwing the following error:

> ERROR: column "max" specified more than once

Can someone explain what I am missing as I have tried this as a query and it worked well.

Comment: try aliasing the columns

Comment: Brilliant!! worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try aliasing the selected expressions:

```
select MAX(row) as max_row,
    "Email",
    MAX("DateUpdated") as max_dateupdated
from "Staging"."DuplicateSubscribers"
group by "Email"
```